# Error when attempting to PUT file to URL with Node request

Tags: node.js, node-request

I am trying to PUT a file to an S3 pre-signed URL. Doing so with bash/cURL works fine but with Node I am getting the following error:

```
Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

Here is the code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

stream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/file');
r = request.put('https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname/path?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=....&...');
stream.pipe(r).on('error', function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Looks like [EPIPE](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#common-system-errors) is coming from a file io error. Assuming your file path is correctly referencing the file, perhaps you may need to call `stream.pipe()` on the read stream's [readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#event-readable) event?

Answer (score 0):

EPIPE means that the writing request failed because the other end closed the connection. Looks like there might be some additional settings required inorder to work with amazon s3. I know that `curl` has native support for multipart/form-data. You can use this library to create readable `multipart/form-data` streams.

https://nicedoc.io/form-data/form-data

- Or you can use third party libraries to send data

https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-upload-stream

https://www.npmjs.com/package/streaming-s3